# jqGrid scrollerbar, height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.5.3.  In the grid definition, I have the following code to set the width & height of the grid.  It sets the grid to be 30% of the page in height & 90% of the page's width.

```
var wid = $(window).width();
var hite = $(window).height();
var ghite = parseInt(hite * 0.3), 10);
var gwid = parseInt(wid * 0.9), 10);
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid({
      ..... url, datatype, colnames, etc
      colModel [ colmodel info for all the columns 
               ],
      width: gwid,
      height: ghite,
      scrollerbar: true,
.... and so on
```

I want to keep the column widths of the columns in the grid as they are, no matter what data is being displayed.  I have a scrollerbar on the grid in case there are more rows than will display at one time.

The issue is when there are fewer rows of data to display.  I still want to keep the grid the same height & width, but one issue is the placeholder for the scrollerbar is still there & makes the grid look like it's not complete.  The other issue is that the blank space where there are no grid rows looks indistinguishable from any existing row in the grid.

Is there a way to do one of the following things?  First option would be to have the scrollerbar placeholder to not take up a portion of the grid's width if it is not needed.  Second option would be to make "empty" space within the grid to look like the header or footer of the grid (same color).

Would appreciate any feedback on if either is possible, or if there's a better way to do this with jqGrid.

**EDIT**

In response to questions regarding what it looks like, I am attaching a picture of what the grid looks like when there are LESS rows than the space allows for, as well as when there are MORE rows than the space allows for.

The image on the left shows the empty space where the scrollbar occupies if there are more rows (or the rows are taller due to word wrap in the columns).  It also shows the "dead" space at the bottom of the grid where there's nothing displaying.

The image on the right shows an example of the grid with the scrollbar, when more records are available than can be shown at one time.

I have tried using:

```
scrollOffset: 0,
```

in the grid definition.  However, while it allows for the recovery of the blank space between the Enabled column & the edge of the grid (shown in picture on the left), it has the unintended consequence of putting both a VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL scrollbar in when the dataset is larger than what can be shown in the grid at one time.

My intent is for the grid to occupy a space within the page that remains the same height & width, whether there are 0, 3 or 100 rows to display in the grid.  Let me know if this info is or is not helpful in clarifying what I was asking for.

[image: Grid Image combined]

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot with a slight explanations?

Comment: Also when you say scroll bar - do you mean vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @avijendr - I am editing the question to clarify & illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the empty space beneath the last row?